# How to retrieve some information from a column using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have this table

[image]

and I want to retrieve account no, amount and date into another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e0d2/11

```
WITH test(str) as (
    SELECT 'Your account 18715240300738 has been credited by NPR 20,784.00 on Apr  4 2016  1:30PM REF: BH691241S6807782849 Thank you'
)
SELECT text, SUBSTRING(str, pos1, pos2 - pos1),
SUBSTRING(text, pos3, pos4 - pos3),
SUBSTRING(text, pos5, pos6-pos5)
FROM sms_text
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
    CHARINDEX('NPR ', text) + 4 AS pos1,
    CHARINDEX(' on ', text) AS pos2,
    CHARINDEX(' account ', text)+8 AS pos3, 
    CHARINDEX(' has ', text) AS pos4,
    CHARINDEX(' on ', text)+3 AS pos5, 
    CHARINDEX(' REF: ', text) AS pos6
) AS CA
```

Comment: wow it worked but i want to retrieve those information from whole row? any ideas for this ? my table table is sms_text and column name is text then how can i apply this logic in my table?

Comment: modified the answer - check it

Comment: but i got a this error "Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." how  to avoid this error?

Comment: can you please filter like where text like '%NPR%'  and refer to this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7b0005/2

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use Regex within your Query.
You can refer this [link](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL) to get regex

Also since you have several variations of Account Number, Amount, and Date
you would have to come up with a set of rules for account number like

1) The word that comes after "Account Number" or "acc/no" or "acc"

2) The word that comes after "INR","NPR" etc

3) The word that comes after "on" and contains "/" or "Jan,Feb,March,April,May,June" etc

Answer (score 0):

The `[text]` column looks like it has been constructed and looks too inconsistent to use string handling or regex to find just the account number (unless you are ok with coding 3 or 4 variations of each based on your data, and then maintaining them). I would rather suggest going to find the source of the data that is in 3NF or similar, and then extracting the data.